# Relation between the norms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X_1=(X_1,(||\cdot||_1)$ and $X_2=(X_2,||\cdot||_2)$ be Banach spaces such that $X_1 \subset X_2$.

**Question.** There exists in general some relation between the norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$? For instance, holds
$$||x||_1 \leq ||x||_2, \; \forall \; x \in X_1 ? \tag{1}$$

I think, for instante, that if $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $ are spaces of continuous functions, then $ (1) $ is true, since norms are defined via $\sup$.

Comment: Is the norm $2$ the restriction of the norm $1$ to the subset $X_2$ ?

Comment: You need the inclusion map to be continuous to get the specific relation that you asked about (well, to get $\leq C\|x\|_2$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust it makes no sense. Since $X_1$ is a subset, no $X_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the converse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1:=C^1([0,1])$ with $||f||_1:=||f||_{\infty} + ||f'||_{\infty} $ and $X_2 :=C^0([0,1])$ with $||f||_2:=||f||_{\infty}$ . Then your inequality (1) gets even reversed. So the answer would be no.